# the changed cells lose their previous formatting

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

After I change one or more cell contents of my qtableview, each changed cell loses its formatting.

Code:

```
...

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
                value =self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
                return str(value)

        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

            if isinstance(value, int):
                return Qt.AlignVCenter + Qt.AlignRight

        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
            if (isinstance(value, int)
                and value < 0):
                return QtGui.QColor('red')

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, (Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.TextAlignmentRole, Qt.ForegroundRole,))
            return True
        return False

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data[0])   
    

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable
```

How can i change the code in order to keep formatting after changing cell content?

[image: enter table on application start]

[image: enter table after changing cell conten]

Comment: You have data that is set indiscriminately, which doesn't make a lot of sense: no matter the role, you always return `self._data[row][column]`. If you want your model to support other roles other than `DisplayRole`, then you must implementat that data structure, either by using a *further* level of nested dictionary, or by using other data containers.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, the error is in my "data" method. Can you please explain exactly where my mistake is. maybe you could show me an example of the correct code.

Comment: Models use *roles* to get and set different aspects of each index, and views call `data()` with multiple times with different roles for each index in order to show it (displayed value, text alignment, etc); you're just storing a single value for each index, which is clearly wrong, because you need to differentiate the role for each index both when reading and writing the data. I strongly suggest you to carefully read the introduction to the [Qt model/view framework](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) in order to understand how it works.